# How to inject $resource into provider?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, angularjs-service, angularjs-provider

I've inherited the following code, and I need to get $resource injected into the service. I'm new to AngularJS and not finding the documentation very helpful. Everything I've tried has failed. Any ideas?

```
(function (angular) {

angular.module('myModule')
    .provider('myService', [myServiceProvider]);

function myServiceProvider() {
    ...
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have access to the dependencies inside provider function because run at config phase. You could get them available by injecting $injector service inside your provider function.

But better and cleaner way would be just inject dependency inside it inside provider `$get` function directly.

**Code**

```
(function (angular) {

    angular.module('myModule')
        .provider('myService', [myServiceProvider]);

    function myServiceProvider() {
        this.$get = function($resource){
            //you could have access here to $resource
            //create $resource object here and return it.
            this.getData = function(){
                return $resource('http://example.com/resource);
            }
        }
    }
)();
```

Comment: @mstrom does it helped you??

Comment: I actually ended up using a factory, due to all the other code in the app using that recipe. This looks good, though. Thanks again,